# Building xunit Jenkins plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to build the [xunit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/xunit-plugin) plugin from source with maven. I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR]   The project org.jenkins-ci.plugins:xunit:1.53-SNAPSHOT (/Users/admin/Downloads/xunit-plugin-master/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:1.410 in guice-maven (http://guice-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

How can I fix the `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

As it says it is not able to get the artifact from online repository.
Try to configure another repo to get the artifact.

```
<settings>
<profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>myprofile</id>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>my-repo2</id>
         <name>your custom repo</name>
         <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
   </profiles>
 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```